# Chef - how to extract zip file

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to extract the zip file type (SAR) with the below code in Chef. The command fails with the message "cannot execute binary file"

thanks for your help.

```
execute 'extract_SAR' do
  command '//home/spsrc0/SAPCAR -xvf KD70254.SAR'
  cwd '/home/spsrc0/bkup_dir'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do not have permissions to execute your SAPCAR file.  You will need to grant yourself execute permissions on that file for whatever group you are running Chef under.  If Chef runs under a group that has the ability to change permissions, then you can change it to:

```
command 'chmod 777 //home/spsrc0/SAPCAR; //home/spsrc0/SAPCAR -xvf KD70254.SAR'
```

(Though it's considered bad practice to set permissions on a file to 777 unless it is actually needed.)  Quite likely, you'll need to set the permissions outside of your recipe, though.